# laravel error when uploading project to production

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrapping

I'm using xampp to develop my project and when y upload it to production I have errors.
I don't have control of the server, it belongs to my university and I have a directory for me (I guess this is called shared server).

In my directory I don't have any 'public_html' folder, it's empty. What I've done is create a folder called 'public', create a folder inside this called 'superadmin', and I've put here the content of the public folder of my project. Then I've upload my project to my directory.

So it looks like this.

```
public
     superadmin
            index.php
            ....
myproject
     app
     bootstrap
     .......
```

I've changed  route of index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/../../myproject/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../myproject/bootstrap/start.php';
```

and the route of path.php from bootstrap

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public/superadmin',
```

But when I run .../mydirectory/public/superadmin/ I get an error in my routes.php

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '['

Route::post('tryLogin', ['uses' => 'Autentication@doLogin']);
```

Of course this runs perfectly in local and there is not any syntax error, I imagine is a problem of a library not found.

I don't know if it's important but in local I have php version 5.4.22 and in the server is 5.3.24

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Short array `[]` syntax was introduced in PHP 5.4, you need to update php in server , or use `array()` instead